# How is one register file enough?

Tags: caching, memory-management

Let's say I'm writing some code in assembly or even in a higher level language, and I compile and run it on a linux OS.

To my best understanding, when my program is running, it uses the CPU 8-array register file, while each array is 32-bit long.
So, my program runs - and can (and does) gain access to each of these 32-bit arrays.

Now my question is this:
How is it, that my computer, and the CPU in particular, can afford to dedicate such an expensive resource - its entire SRAM cache memory, no less - to one simple C/C++ program, while surely, it has much more important things to do with it, and much more extensive, demanding processes to run on background?
I'd expect that my simple C/C++ program will get a nice slice from the RAM to run on.

Comment: The short answer is that both the operating system and the CPU work together to share time between all the processes that need to use these resources. That is their job. Their only job. Much of the real estate on the CPU chip is intended to make access to memory, especially the register file, as efficient as possible for multiple, mostly independent, tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If there are 2 tasks that both want to use the CPU, and only one CPU in the machine, then one of them will be running and the other one will be waiting. Once in a while, a timer interrupt arrives, causing the CPU to stop running the currently active job and jump to the kernel's interrupt handler.

The kernel might decide to resume the current task, or to give the other one a chance. If neither one voluntarily yields the CPU (to wait for data from disk or network for example) then the kernel will switch back and forth between them a few times per second.

The decision of exactly when to switch tasks is a delicate balance: allowing a single process to monopolize the CPU for a long time makes other processes seem non-responsive, but switching too often would make CPU caches less effective (after a switch the cache contents left behind by the old process are not likely to be useful to the new process).

So from the CPU's point of view, there's no such thing as "running in the background". There's just one running task, and everything else is just data sitting in memory waiting to be used.

Your idea of processes getting a "slice" of the CPU is not completely wrong - you're just slicing in the wrong dimension. Processes don't get slices of the register file; they get the whole CPU for slices of time. They're called *timeslices*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a distinction between registers and caches (and all kinds of other things involved in modern multitasking machines):

1. Register file is indeed exclusively allocated to your program for a duration of a scheduler time slot. However, it's not such a big deal to reload it in full on a context switch - after all, you may end up reloading the whole register file on a simple function call (if your function has plenty of local variables).
2. Cache is more complicated. First, it is very dependent on a particular CPU implementation - simpler/older CPUs can indeed flush the cache on a context switch, but no modern higher end CPU will do this. If cache is "physically mapped" (cache address tags correspond to physical memory locations and virtual address translation happens before cache access) then neither CPU nor OS have to do anything special on context switch. "Logically mapped" caches (the ones which use virtual addresses to tag the cache lines, so as to reduce the cache access latency a bit) will often feature additional "task tags" on each line. The OS, on context switch, will set some value to "task id" register which will be used by cache hardware to establish, whether whatever line belongs to the currently running process or should be replaced.